# Correct way for dynamically insertion and deletion of HTML tags using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, insert

I'm not a web expert, but I need help with good practices using JQuery.

**My problem:**
I have a big table of items. Each item has a button to add it into other section of the page, so I need to extract the content and set it into a new element.

I wrote [this code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk4Ut/), but I'm not sure that it is the correct way of solving this (but it works).

Other option I have in mind is to have an id with the number of the row that I want to copy and process the text to obtain the values by e.g. $('name-'+id). This should be as follows:

```
<tr id='row-1'>
    <td id='name-1' class='name'>First</td>
    <td id='lastname-1' class='lastname'>Brand</td>
    <td>
        <button id='btnTest-1' class='btnTest'>Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for your comments or advices!

Comment: you can add each item countless times. is that the intent?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add them many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use incremental `id` or `class` attributes. It turns in to a maintenance nightmare.

You could improve the code you've got by using `closest()` and `find()` instead of chained `parent()` and `children()` calls respectively. Also, you could use a delegated event for the dynamically added buttons. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnTest').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var name = $tr.find('.name').text();
        var lastname = $tr.find('.lastname').text();
        $('#names').append('<div><span>' + name + ' ' + lastname + '</span><button class="delName">Delete name</button></div>');
    });

    $('#names').on('click', '.delName', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk4Ut/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your complete and quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs correctly, but I recommend several optimizations:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnTest').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $parent = $(this).parent(),
            name = $parent.prevAll('.name').text(),
            lastname = $parent.prev().text(),
            obj = $('#names').append('<div><span>' + name + ' ' + lastname + '</span><button class="delName">Delete name</button></div>');

        obj.find('.delName').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
});
```

This version makes better use of caching, avoids the double declaration of `.parent()` and `.children()`, because the `.prev()` and `.find()` methods will be much faster. It also consolidates your variable declaration into a single statement, which will make your minified code much smaller.

[Here is an updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk4Ut/5/)

**EDIT**

You should also be using `.text()` instead if `.html()`, modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections and the details! A little 'optimization' question: is it common to make appends even if they are big sections? Is it more practical to make a clone of a hidden section and then fill it with correct data ?

Comment: its more about maintainability than speed. If you clone a huge section and then modify 100 elements in there, it will take forever and be super messy, rather than just appending the new data. its always a balance, so best i can say is test both methods and see which works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

change you click handler so it uses event delegation and the **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method so it keeps listening to new elements added to the DOM

```
obj.on("click", '.delName', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Wk4Ut/2/**

you just need to reference the **obj** and the event will listen for clicks on the **.delname** and bubble up to the parent. No need to use children().children()

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the doc for on()